# How to caluculate the sum of increasing percentage of decreasing total area

Tags: java

Let's say there is a big pizza, the first person takes 1% of the pizza, the second person takes 2% of the remaining pizza(the remaining is the thing left after first person takes that 1% away), the third person, likewise, takes 3% of the remaining.

I want to caluculate the total percentage of pizza that N people take away.

For example, if N =1, the total will be 1%.
if N = 2, the total will be 2% * 99/100.

If total is too complicated, I accept solution that calculates one specific person's percentage as well.

My attempt:

```
        int n = 5;
        double remaining =1.0;
        for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
          remaining -= remaining * i / 100.0;
        }
        double totalTaken = 1.0 - remaining;
```

I couldn't complete the for loop because I dont know what to put in...
Also, it would be nice to simplify the code for one person's percentage

Comment: Duplicate of this Money Stack Exchange question: [Compound Interest Formula With Monthly Investment Increase](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/86789/compound-interest-formula-with-monthly-investment-increase).

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen thank you, didn't know math related coding questions can be found in finance...

Comment: Well you are basically just asking for a formula to compute compound interest.  But maybe in the context of Java you didn't turn anything up :-)

Comment: I would just compute it numerically. Keep track of the area of the pizza. Each person takes away n/100th of the remaining area. Subtract that from the previous area. Repeat until done.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen There is a difference between the monthly investment question and my question. The percentage of the investement is fixed at 2%, whereas for my question, the percentage increases person after person, while the total decreases.

Comment: @NomadMaker Could you please me write a solution even mathematically? it doesn't have to be in code. Even purely math is fine. Technically, I can manually calculate each person's area, but I want a formula that does the job. Basically I want the smart way

Comment: I don't have a formula. I would just do this purely numerically.

Comment: @NomadMaker ok thanks for the suggestion. I will try it, although I prefer a code/formula that produces the answer more universally